# Observable that stores last value, but cannot push new ones?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java3

Let's say I have an `Person` interface, that have an `name` observable:

```
interface Person {
  Observable<String> name;
}
```

And it's implementation:

```java
class David implements Person {
  Observable<String> name = BehaviorSubject<>.createDefault("David");
}
```

And now there is a problem, because I can't get current value of `name` observable:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person = PersonFactory.create();
    System.out.println(??person.name.currentValue??);
  }
}
```

I don't want to expose the name as BehaviorSubject in my interface, because then everyone would be able to change the name, which isn't what I want.

I kind of understand a logic of Observables, so I know they aren't designed to store any value. So what is "an immutable observable with current value" in RxJava?

In Android there is a `LiveData` and `MutableLiveData`. To my understanding `MutableLiveData` is the equivalent of `BehaviorSubject`, so what is the equivalent of `LiveData` in RxJava?

Comment: Hmm, what's your desired behavior here? How do you update value emitted by the `name` Observable? Why are you returning the name as an `Observable`, instead of just a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to create my own `LiveData`, using a field delegation

```
interface LiveData<out T> {
    val observable: Observable<out T>
    val value: T

    fun subscribe(onNext: Consumer<in T>): Disposable = observable.subscribe(onNext)
}

class MutableLiveData<T>(initial: T) : LiveData<T> {
    private val subject: BehaviorSubject<T> = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(initial)

    override val observable: Observable<out T> = subject

    override var value: T
        get() = subject.value
        set(value) = subject.onNext(value)

    fun mutate(mutationFunction: T.() -> Unit) {
        value.mutationFunction()
        value = value
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm interested to know where you're going to be using this? I've normally used this pattern to make reactive repositories e.g. a place to set data and notify observers when it has changed like a user profile or a shopping cart.

Comment: Also seems a little over complicated and unnecessary to pass a "mutation function".

Answer (score 1):

Define the type of varaible `name` as a subject internally to `David` and use the `hide()` method to expose as an observable. The use of hide will ensure the outside world can't invoke `onNext` i.e. mutate the name. [See the docs for hide() here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#hide--)

```
class David implements Person {
  
    private PublishSubject<String> nameSubject = BehaviorSubject<>.createDefault("David");

    public Observable<String> observeName() {
        return nameSubject.hide();
    }

    // If you want the outside world to update the name
    public void setName(String name) {
        nameSubject.onNext(name)
    }
}
```